# Extract rows from a dataframe based on machine ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe with 100 ID, each ID referees to a machine and for each ID (machine) I have multiple records, just like the picture below:
[image]

I want to extract 30% of records for each ID and put it separately in a new dataframe.
Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby`+[`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
dataframe.groupby('Id', as_index=False).sample(frac=0.3)
```

Comment: I got this error  "ValueError: Only integers accepted as `n` values"

​

Comment: @Sam sorry, I forgot the parameter name, check the updated answer. I also added a link to the doc.